# Mac GDB Client Standalone Application

Tags: php, debugging, macos, gdb, xdebug

Since MacGDBp from bluestatic.org seems to be discontinued, is there another way to debug PHP applications with xDebug using a a standalone app for Mac OS X?

I use TextMate as my primary editor, and I'd rather not switch to NetBeans or Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where you read that it was discontinued. A new beta version was just released:

https://www.bluestatic.org/blog/2011/01/15/macgdbp-1-4-beta-2/

Comment: You're right. bluestatic.org seems to have been down that day. Thanks.